# Magento installation on windows shows Database connection error on xampp?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.4

I am using the xampp Version 1.6.4 with PHP Version 5.2.4 and I am trying to Install the Magento latest version on xampp.I got the error in the configuration page.That is, it shows the **'Database connection error.'**.
Fields I filled up in the Page:

***Database Connection***

1. Host    -----                   localhost
2. Database Name----              Magento(already created in phpMyadmin)
3. User Name        -----          root
4. Password ----- blank

***Web access options***

1. Base URL ------ http://127.0.0.1/magento/
2. Admin Path ------  admin
3. Enable Charts ---- Checked
4. Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step --Checked
5. Use Web Server (Apache) Rewrites --- Unchecked
6. Use Secure URLs (SSL)  ---- Unchecked

***Session Storage Options***

11.Save Session Data In -- File system

I already created the Magento database in the phpMyadmin.But when I click continue it displays error.I dont know why?Please help me in this.

***Update:*** phpMyadminConfiguration

```
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = '';
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning']  = FALSE;
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp';
$i = 0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'localhost'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';         
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';         
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl']           = false;       
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';       
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';     
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;       
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '';          
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = '';          // access to the "mysql/user"
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';      
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '';     
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonSession'] = '';         
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonURL']     = '';          
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['LogoutURL']     = '';          
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['nopassword']    = FALSE;       
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db']       = '';          
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db']       = '';         
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']       = '';          
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']         = '';
```

Comment: Is the password actually blank or were you just hiding it for security? Perhaps it requires a password to be non-empty.

Comment: Its actually empty only.I didnt Hide anything here.Because its a loalserver only.Even thats not connected with Internet.

Comment: @clockworkgeek After Setting the password to my localhost phpmyadmin it wont display the Database connection error.But it wont go to next page and also Base URL ------ http://127.0.0.1/magento/ change to Base URL ------ http://localhost/magento/ I dont know why?

Comment: If the database has been populated by the installer already check the `core_config_data` table for `base_url` values. These should all have a period in them, so use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost".

Answer (score 6):

Go to users within phpMyAdmin.
Make sure the `host` for the user you're entering in Magento is set to `localhost` and not `%` (any).

Answer (score 6):

This is a pretty old question but I came across it recently and I hope this answer helps someone else.  My issue came down to an old version of Magento on top of a new WAMP installation.  Since MySQL 5.6.1, the **have_innodb** variable has been removed.  However, the Magento installer checks for that variable and throws an error if it doesn't find it.  If you actually check the exception log you'll see an error that the database server does not support InnoDB.  Yet in the `catch` handler it only logs that exception and throws a generic "Database connection error" message.

The simplest fix, if you're sure your DB supports InnoDB, is to simply edit `app\code\core\Mage\Install\Model\Installer\Db.php`, find the `checkDatabase` method, and comment out the portion at the end of the `try` block that checks for **have_innodb**.  Normally, I would not advocate editing core files, but this is only to get the installer working, so I'd say it's safe enough.

Hope that helps anyone else in a similar situation.

Comment: thanks it worked for me on a Magento 1.5 installation even if the error message was 'Database connection error.' instead of 'Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine.' which has been commented out for the fix.

Comment: This is really an old post but I have to tell you.. You are a lifesaver! Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but after using host:port it worked perfectly. In my case its 127.0.0.1:3306

Comment: Looks like using "localhost" probably not resolving correctly, instead 127.0.0.1 works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change at Database connection settings host to 127.0.0.1

Comment: I already tried that with 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:80,(both with http) and also http://localhost.I got the same error

Comment: What configuration have phpmyadmin?

Comment: I updated my Question for displaying the configuration of phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  It appears it is related to a DNS issue in that Magento is looking for a valid type URL of the form http://xxxxxx.xxx  where x is whatever name you create.  Dont use a .com, .net etc..create some random one .ecs for example.  You can't use 127.0.0.1 as the URL or localhost for Magento (at least that was my experience using XAMPPLITE.

I downloaded HostXpert (free) and assigned a dummy URL like demo.ecs to 127.0.0.1 and then did the Magento install to demo.ecs

Before you do the install, verify that your localhost demo.ecs works when you load it into your browser.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You don't need to download a program for it, just edit the "HOSTS" file in your windows' system folder.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using XAMPP for local development. In that case, you may want to also checkout [BitNami Magento](http://bitnami.org/stack/magento). It is very similar to XAMPP in that it is free, multiplatform and self-contained, but it comes with Magento preinstalled by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an all privileges account **with** a  password  on your magento database. Once you click continue Magento will populate the database with a whole bunch of tables. It can take a few minutes depending on your connection or your PC (for local installations).

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve your problem.

1. Type `localhost` and <kbd>enter</kbd>
2. Select `english` option
3. `localhost/xampp/index.php` page will come
4. Left sidebar have `security` tab, click on that
5. `localhost/security/index.php` page will come
6. Set your username `root` and password (as u want)
7. Go for installation process and fill \

Database Connection:

```
Host ----- localhost
Database Name---- Magento(already created in phpMyadmin)
User Name ----- root
Password ----- you have set above
```

That's all perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I think for magneto database you need to access to the local host area but  let's say we have a site like `http://yoursite.com` and if we substitute anything at the place of `com` then what will be the procedures? I have multiple sites and going to set this but I do not want to get errors.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a permissions problem.

I had given the user grant all permissions from the commandline but on rechecking through phpMyAdmin (because of this error) I noticed that the user did not have the permissions I had set.

Once I corrected this it worked.

The users section is shown in the image below:

[phpMyAdmin Users Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okO5A.png)